# unable to locate element , alt src image link

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

Trying to fetch the image link of channel icon image and banner image link from youtube but Unable to locate element.

refer the below image :

[image]

Code i have tried for channel icon image:

```
channel_icon = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "/html/body/ytd-app/div/ytd-page-manager/ytd-browse[2]/div["
    "3]/ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer/tp-yt-app-header-layout/div/tp-yt-app-header/div[2]/div[2]/div/div["
    "1]/yt-img-shadow/img").get_attribute("alt src")
print(channel_icon)
```

also it should work for every channel.

url for inspect -> https://www.youtube.com/c/FlyingBeast320/videos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like

```
channel_icon =  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='channel-header-container']//img").get_attribute("src")
print(channel_icon)

banner_img = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//ytd-c4-tabbed-header-renderer'
).get_attribute('style').split(
    '--yt-channel-banner:url('
)[1].split(');')[0].replace('\\', '')
print(banner_img)
```

Comment: working thanks. did you able to find the cover picture banner image link ?

Comment: Oh great . Thanks a ton ! can you please tell how did you find it ?

Comment: @pkk just a lot of experience in web scrapping)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below `css selector`  :

```
div#channel-header-container img
```

in code :

```
channel_icon = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#channel-header-container img").get_attribute("src")
print(channel_icon)
```

Comment: it is giving some other icon, it is giving small instagram icon from cover banner picture area

Comment: updated just now, please try again. with the above solution, you should get this https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/favicon-tbn?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6YOpVr0ZbF_xB21xW3ZZEoCHNP-ndI6ZcdT7qos8JOy0GPZTbs_dPHo49MU9g1i4OmQBxUFkajAOlJUw14kOUCWd61IjLZ2TXBI8 - as an output.

Comment: not working i should get this link -> https://yt3.ggpht.com/ytc/AKedOLQOc0cCDSOZTH58A27GDWUlaoaq-h_loyNQPhRV4Q=s88-c-k-c0x00ffffff-no-rj

Comment: updated the entire code above with css, hope it helps

Comment: working now thanks for your efforts. also are able to find the cover picture banner image link, i didnt able to find it !

Comment: yes, I think my previous xpath was locating that, let me check it for you

Comment: No, I think that's not clickable right  ? Did you try that manually ? I see this `href="null"`

Comment: exactly i also saw the same -> href="null"

Comment: it makes sense,  cause I cannot click on that manually as well. Do you still want to retrieve null value ?

Comment: no ! that null is clickable is not giving anything it is redirecting link is not valid.